# Is it common to declare variables of interface type instead of implement it?

Tags: java, interface

I have been reading a book called "Head First Design Patterns-A brain friendly guide" by Eric Freeman & Elizabeth Robson. All of their examples are in Java.

On page 15, what they have done is:

- **In a duck class, two variables of interface type are declared.** Please see the image.

[image]

As a newbie in Java, I have always thought the way to utilize interface is via "implement", but this example surely got me thinking.

May I ask if it is a common practice to use interface this way? I could have completely missed something here.

Thank you

Comment: thank you for pointing this out @Sotirios